# Validate a custom form with js and php

Tags: php, plugin-development, javascript, forms, validation

I would please need help with the following: I have a form in my WP Plugin, that is validated with js, which works fine, Then I want to validate it using php, display the errors on the form and after it is submitted without errors I want to process the form with php and redirect.
Js works, but after submit, it redirects to wmcode-handle-form.php (Page not found) without any processing. I'm really stuck here for weeks, so thank you in advance.

page-yoda.php

```
<form id="my-form" action="wmcode-handle-form.php" name="my-form" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)"method="post">

  <div>
    <label for="firstname">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" >
    <?php if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] === 'firstname') { ?>
       <span class="error-message">Invalid first name. Please enter 'Yoda'.</span>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

wmcode-handle-form.php

```
// Perform PHP validation
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

// If validation fails, redirect back to the form page with error messages and entered values
if (!validateName($firstname)) {
  $queryString = http_build_query([
    'error' => 'firstname',
    'name' => $firstname
  ]);

  header("Location: page-yoda.php?" . $queryString);
  exit();
}

// If validation passes, continue processing the form data
// Functions for validation
function validateName($name) {
  // Your name validation logic
  if ($name !== 'Yoda') {
    return false; // Validation fails if name is not 'Yoda'
  }
  
  return true; // Validation passes if name is 'Yoda'
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be submitting the form directly to a PHP file! You're also going to find that the form will submit to different URLs based on the page the form is on because you used a relative path to the PHP file. It also means solving the problem you asked about becomes 10x harder. Instead use `action=""` to submit to the same page displaying the form, then handle the form and validation in the same place you display the form

Comment: Thank you for your response, this solves the redirection problem, but neither the js nor the php (on same page) is processed

Comment: there is no CSS or JS in your question to debug, I also only just realised you weren't redirecting to a page, you were redirecting to a theme template which is also not something you should ever do. Browsers should never make direct requests to theme templates, those files are just templates loaded by WordPress, they aren't the pages themselves. There is no way to make `header("Location: page-yoda.php?" . $queryString);` work, that approach is a dead end. Can you edit in your JS and CSS into the question as well as screenshots?